# I can't run an android app because of a seemingly missing unknown parent resource?

Tags: java, android, gradle, apk, compatibility

I keep on getting the same error messages in both android studio and eclipse when I try to run my app on my phone(Samsung Galaxy S7 edge). Instead of posing a long question I will just post the pictures here. Hopefully someone has an answer for me. I asked a couple of friends of mine and one tells me it has to do with the sdk version I have installed on my computer but I have the latest android sdk installed on android studio and the other tells me that I have to change the parent value in my gradle file (see image 1 and 2) to the one I mentioned in the xml file. However I don't see any parent value in the gradle file(image 1) to change to the parent value mentioned in image 2.

Thanks a lot in advance.

[Screenshot of the Build.gradle(module: app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWJXR.png)

[Screenshot of the XML "v24/ Values tab" + error message output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpseR.png)

Comment: Update your build.gradle file dependencies to the latest version along. Note that you will need to have an internet connection for the dependencies to be downloaded by Android Studio.

Comment: `play-services:+`, besides being a horrible choice due to including all 15+ Play services dependencies and providing unpredictable builds given to it automatically updating your dependencies (always use a fixed number), currently pulls in a a version of the Support Library starting with `26`, meaning you need a `compileSdkVersion` of 26 as well.